# Can I join mysql table dynamic

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to write this query but its not working

```
SELECT a.a1,a.a2, if(a.a3=1,b.b1,c.c1) as d1
FROM mytbl1 a
LEFT JOIN if(a.a3=1,mytbl2 b,mytbl3 c) on if(a.a3=1,a.a4=b.b4,a.a4=c.c4)
```

What I want is if my a3 is equals to 1 then I wanted to join mytbl2 otherwise mytbl3 its column name and everything is different

Can I use something like what I've tried with some modifications or any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this by left joining both tables and adding this condition to the join ON clause. This will essentialy always join both tables but only one of the tables values will have values and the other will have nulls :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytbl1 a
LEFT JOIN mytbl2 b ON(a.a4=b.b4 AND a.a3 = 1)
LEFT JOIN mytbl3 c ON(a.a4=c.c4 AND a.a3 <> 1)
```

Comment: will it work if a.a3 value is string for example :

ON(a.a4=c.c4 AND a.a3 <> 'Activity')

Comment: @BillGates Yes. Thats the query you need